# How do you export higher resolution 360° VR footage from Adobe Premiere?

Tags: premiere, adobe

We have recently purchased a 6-lens 360° 8k camera. It is fantastic. However, I have only been able to find [instructions](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/kb/work-with-vr.html) on how to export video at a max width of 4096. This is half the size that we can record in. So if we can only export at 4096, what is the point of shooting 8k? Is there a way to export at the full resolution from Adobe Premiere?

Any feedback, suggestions or links on how to make use of the 8k footage would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You can find more on this topic in a similar discussion [How do I encode videos into h.264 at 8k resolution](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/21260/how-do-i-encode-videos-into-h-264-at-8k-resolution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find this [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1IJPtQMzKMw) if anyone else is interested. It provides the best settings for exporting 8k video from Premiere.